# How can I export GLTF models using KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness from threejs editor

Tags: three.js, 3d, gltf

does anyone know how to export models from threejs editor that support the GLTF KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness extension?

I found that the THREEJS GLTFExporter supports the extension as well as the importer. However, I could not find how to export a 3D object from threejs editor that supports this extension KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness.

Background:
I've created an object with a MeshPhysicalMaterial inside the threejs editor but whenever I export it to GLTF and import it into my app it has a MeshStandardMaterial. I do understand why it becomes a MeshStandardMaterial from looking at the code. However, I'm thinking that using the KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness extension I might get the importer to use another material.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import a `glTF` model in the editor that uses `KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness`, the respective `glTF` exporter will honor this setting and export the extension again. However, it's currently not possible to force the export to `KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness`. `GLTFExporter` does not provide an option for this.

If you require this feature, consider to make a feature request at github.

`three.js R113`

Comment: Thank you. Yes I would require that feature. Would you know any other 3D authoring tool that supports exports with the material extension?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. AFAIK, the exporter of bayblon.js actually converts `SpecularGlossiness` to `MetallicRoughness`.

Comment: Substance Painter would be a good tool for this sort  of thing, but isn't free.

Comment: Does the import/load still honor `KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness` with the current version of threejs (0.150.1)? When I load a model I get a warning: `THREE.GLTFLoader: Unknown extension "KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness".` and the model never shows the textures...

Comment: `KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness` is not supported since `r147` anymore. Use the following guide to convert your assets: https://www.donmccurdy.com/2022/11/28/converting-gltf-pbr-materials-from-specgloss-to-metalrough/